# How to wait for the page to load before clicking in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the content of my Chrome extension:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Zero",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "Auto fill form GRC",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon/icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["extension.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
            min-width: 120px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            }
            
            input, textarea {
            width: 140px;
            }
            
            input#save {
            font-weight: bold;
            width: auto;
            
            }
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>GRC</h1>
        <center>
            <div>
                <label><b>Veuillez saisir un code</b></label>
                <input name="inpt" id="inpt" autocomplete="off"/>
                <p>
                    <button id="btn">Enter</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setUpStuff, false);
function setUpStuff(){
    let optionsButton = document.getElementById('btn');
    optionsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {functionnum: document.getElementById("inpt").value.toUpperCase()});
        });
      });
}
```

**extension.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender) {
    let functions = {
    1: function () {
document.getElementById("topsearch-text").value += "google";
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("go");
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) list[i].click();
document.querySelector('img[src="https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/google-pixel7-pro-new.jpg"]').click(); 
},
    2: function () { alert(2); },
    3: function () { alert(3); },
    }
    functions[request.functionnum]();
});
```

as you can see on the extension.js file I have the number 1 function which is executed for example on the website: https://www.gsmarena.com/
I have to write in the search field the word google then press the go button and I have to wait for the result then press the model google_pixel_7_pro.

I used the setTimeout method but without success the code stops after the second click here is a demonstration video in gif format

[A demonstration video in gif format](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/sitepoint/original/3X/7/6/76bef5acb15bf962a62af17d3d7eb41211cccaa4.gif)

I hope I have explained my need well and thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post the error as text, not as code. Also fix your syntax

Comment: Note that `document.getElementsByName(...)` returns a list, but you try to access the `value` property of the list rather than of each of elements/the first.

Comment: On the surface, it does not seem like you must have a background page. Since you have a popup and the user interacts with that popup, it can execute scripts on a web page as well using the same mechanism wOxxOm showed you. You do not need content scripts if you go down this route, unless you want to send them a message and they would execute the code.

Comment: yes you are right thank you @PhistucK I managed to solve my problem without the backgroud.js